# No such file or directory but file exist

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I installed pcl. There is a pcl folder under `user/include/pcl-1.7`. I add `#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>` line to cpp file. On terminal, I try to compile this file.

```
g++ -c test.cpp 
fatal error: pcl/ModelCoefficients.h: No such file or directory
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Being a good programmer requires observational skills, and it does not take much observational skill to spot that "pcl" is not the same as "plc". -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "plc" is an only spelling error. I edit now.

Comment: Is `user/include/pcl-1.7` really the correct path? Not `/usr/include/pcl-1.7`? `user/include/pcl-1.7` is a relative path, since it doesn't start with `/`; relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-I` to tell the compiler to search the `user/include/plc-1.7` path for header files:

```
g++ -Iuser/include/plc-1.7 -c test.cpp
```

More info:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: Did you make sure that the path is really a valid relative path? (It's a relative path if it doesn't begin with `/` or `~`.) I doubt it, because usually header files are located in `/usr/include` rather than `user/include`.